# Data comparison between Sybase and Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle, sybase

We need to compare the data available in Sybase tables to data available in Oracle tables. Can we use checksum to quickly compare? Data in tables are very huge, so checking row by row via code would be time consuming. Any help is appreciated

can we compare checksum in Sysbase to checksum in Oracle? would it be same?

Comment: Hey, @IntelJK, welcome to StackOverflow. For the benefit for potential answerers, can you post a small example of sample Sysbase and Oracle objects and how you would compare their checksums? Thanks!

Comment: The likelihood of two binary objects (an oracle table and a sybase table) having the same checksum even if all of the data in both tables were the same is very small. Conceptually, if the checksums were the same, you'd be able to copy a sybase table to oracle and it would just work. You _might_ be able to export each table to a text file (assuming none of the columns have binary data in them), and then do a diff, but I highly suspect ordering would be different.

Comment: @SalmonKiller and KevinO Appreciate your response. e.g. I have a table in Sybase with 15 columns and > 5 million records. As part of ETL every quarter, we do transformation and check data quality between Sybase and Oracle. As of now, we do it by querying DB (both Sybase and Oracle) which is taking very longer time. If we have option to quick get checksum on Sybase and Oracle and compare, that would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: or as a matter of fact, any other method to quickly check if both the tables or query results are same, then we can confirm the result, if mismatches, then we can get into row by row validation

Comment: SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN 2, COLUMN3..... COLUMN15 FROM TABLE 1 - Sybase. Can we get checksum for this output? likewise for oracle, so I can compare and confirm, both the results are identical. If not identical, I will scan through row by row. But, this will help 90% of the result, only 10% I need to scan through row by row. Thanks